# Stuck with foreach loop

Tags: php, mysql, loops, dynamic, foreach

Im trying to insert data from dynamic form. In my form there are fields. If user presses button then another empty field will be added what use then can fill with information.

For example lets say ive got 2 inputs (input1_2, input2_2 are created with js after perssing the button):

```
 input1:              input2:
 input1_2:            input2_2:

        (add more field)
```

So lets say that ive entered so:

```
 input1: CAT          input2: 2
 input1_2: DOG        input2_2: 3

        (add more field)
```

So i would like to echo out CAT 2 and DOG 3. 
I tryed using foreach loop inside foreach loop but im missing something.
When i do so i get:

```
CAT 2
CAT 3
DOG 2
DOG 3
```

I undestand why its doing so, but i cant figure out solution for my problem. Could anyone give me hint or something?
Thank you

Php code:

```
$nimi_60=$_POST['nimi_60'];
$paev_60=$_POST['paev_60'];
foreach ($nimi_60 as $value_nimi_60)
  {
     foreach ($paev_60 as $value_paev_60)
        {           
        echo $value_nimi_60.' '.$value_paev_60.'</br>';
        }                 
      }
```

Comment: The internet crawls with info on these topics. What have you tried?

Comment: post some code so we can help you with the code..

Comment: And please provide some code ..

Comment: Show your foreach loops and somebody will point on your mistake.

Comment: What is result of $nimi_60=$_POST['nimi_60']; and $paev_60=$_POST['paev_60']; ?

Comment: $nimi_60=$_POST['nimi_60'] comes from input1 and $paev_60=$_POST['paev_60'] comes from input2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are sure that $nimi_60 and $paev_60 contain the same number of elements, you can do:

```
$nimi_60 = $_POST['nimi_60'];
$paev_60 = $_POST['paev_60'];
foreach ($nimi_60 as $value_nimi_60) {
    echo $value_nimi_60 . ' ' . current($paev_60) . '</br>';
    next($paev_60);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I think you're doing what you're doing, try:

```
$nimi_60 =& $_POST['nimi_60'];
$paev_60 =& $_POST['paev_60'];

$result = array();

foreach ( $nimi_60 as $key_nimi_60 => $value_nimi_60 ) {
    if ( isset( $paev_60[ $key_nimi_60 ] ) {
        $result[ $value_nimi_60 ] = (int) $paev_60[ $key_nimi_60 ];
    }
}

foreach ( $result as $index => $count ) {
    echo $index ." ". $count. </br>';
}
```

Otherwise, how does your keys in $nimi_60 & $paev_60 look? Post a print_r from both arrays please.